# How to get midi track instrument name with python?

Tags: python, midi, music21, midi-instrument

The only way to do it I found is to use **music21**:

```
m = converter.parse(path)
for m in m.parts:
    print(m[0])
```

but it's output is incorrect:

```
Piano


Piano
```

empty places is also an instrument names, it just can't read it, but problem is not in file, cause I can import it to the **tuxguitar** correctly. Also music21 can't pase big midi files and stuck. I tried mido library, but there is no way to get track instrument, I found an [attribute](http://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta_message_types.html#instrument-name-0x04), but have no ideas how to use it.

**How can I parse instruments of midi tracks with python?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't Mido work?

```
from mido import MidiFile
mid = MidiFile('song.mid')  
for i, track in enumerate(mid.tracks):
    print('Track {}: {}'.format(i, track.name))
    for msg in track:
        print(msg)
```

The tracks attribute is a list of tracks. Each track is a list of messages and meta messages, with the time attribute of each messages set to its delta time (in ticks).
More info can be found [here](http://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/midi_files.html#midi-files).

Comment: I need to get an Instrument name (Piano, Sax etc.), not the midi events. Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: I found it! your code outputs value "program" besides other events, it's instrument value.

Answer (score 5):

Instruments are set in MIDI Files in a **program change** message.

For instance:

```
mid = mido.MidiFile('PaintItBlack.mid')

for msg in mid:
    if msg.type == 'program_change':
        print(msg)
```

This will yield

```
program_change channel=1 program=32 time=0
program_change channel=2 program=27 time=0
program_change channel=3 program=27 time=0
program_change channel=4 program=27 time=0
program_change channel=5 program=25 time=0
program_change channel=6 program=27 time=0
program_change channel=7 program=104 time=0
program_change channel=8 program=30 time=0
program_change channel=10 program=52 time=0
```

where the channel program value is the instrument for that channel.

For example, program 27 is an Electric Guitar.

Refer to https://jazz-soft.net/demo/GeneralMidi.html to find program instruments.